# Query returns empty set when parameters are passed from GET variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a simple query with a where clause that has no results when it is run from code.

This query works fine if it is ran from the SQL Server Management studio, but when i pass some variables that are taken from GET parameters this query will show no results.`Request.QueryString["q"]` is not `NULL`.`Command.ExecuteReader();` executes fine.

```
Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Connection.Open();
        Command = new SqlCommand("", Connection);
        if (Request.QueryString["q"] != null)
        {
            Query = Request.QueryString["q"].ToString();
            Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [device] WHERE [display_name] LIKE N'%@query%' OR [address] LIKE N'%@query%' ";
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@query", Query);
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

            while (Reader.Read())//Here Reader.HasRows=False
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
```

There is a single row in the table that has its `[display_name]` is equal to `KHR` and its `[address]` is equal to `تست`. 
passing `?q=kh` to the page, i get no result form this query where it actually should return a single row.

Comment: Try removing the N'% and the final %' then add to the variable Query the %

Comment: @Steve tried that now. still no results. However, if i replace `@query` in `'%@query%'` with a constant value such as k, i get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[display_name] LIKE N'%@query%'` will search for a row where `display_name` contains the text `'@query'` **not** the value of the variable `@query`. C# doesn't inject the value of a parameter.
You need to do something like this:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [device] WHERE [display_name] LIKE N'%' + @query + N'%' OR [address] LIKE N'%' + @query + N'%';";
Command.Parameters.Add("@query", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
Command.Parameters["@query"].Value = Query;
```

*Note I have also removed `AddWithValue` ([Can we stop using AddWithValue Already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/))*